# Validación de fecha en DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Quiero hacer una validación de un `DateTimePicker`, cuando no cumpla la condición (arriba de 20 meses) no me permita guardar un `Textbox` (llamado preñada).

Alguna ayuda o sugerencias

**Código Avanzado:**

```
Private Sub Btnguardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnguardar.Click
    If Txtnombre.Text <> "" And Cbocondicion.Text <> "" And Txtfecha_entrada.Text <> "" And Txtnumero.Text <> "" And Cboorigen.Text <> "" And Cboraza.Text <> "" And CboSexo.Text <> "" Then
        If Txtnombre.Text = Txtnombre.Text Then
            Try
                Dim dt As New Vbovino
                Dim fu As New Fbovino

                dt._Nombre = Txtnombre.Text
                dt._Condicion_fisica = Cbocondicion.Text
                dt._Fecha_entrada = Txtfecha_entrada.Text
                dt._Numero = Txtnumero.Text
                dt._Origen = Cboorigen.Text
                dt._Raza = Cboraza.Text
                If CboSexo.Text = "hembra" And Cboestado.Text = "Preñada" And calDateTimePicker2.Value < Now Then
                    MsgBox("No se puede agregar el bovino")
                    Return
                Else
                    dt._Sexo = CboSexo.Text
                    dt._Estado_reproductor = Cboestado.Text
                    dt._Fecha_nacimiento = calDateTimePicker2.Value
                End If
                dt._Peso = Txtpeso.Text
                dt._Estado = 1


                If fu.insertar(dt) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Bovino registrado correctamente", "guardando registros ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    mostrar()
                    Limpiar()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Bovino NO registrado ", " intente nuevamente ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    mostrar()
                    Limpiar()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Las contraseñas no coinciden ", " intente nuevamente ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Falta ingresar datos ", " intente nuevamente ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código donde que tienes avanzado, indicando dónde quieres validarlo. Asimismo, especificar como quieres validar la condición de los 20 meses. Si te pones a leer tu pregunta no indicas si estás utilizando dos DateTimePickers.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas juanfer,

Puedes usar la función [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) de la siguiente manera:

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Now, calDateTimePicker2.Value) > 20 Then

    *** CÓDIGO ***

End If
```

Comment: perfecto, fue de mucha ayuda, solucionado